# Valid Geometric Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), the definition of a Geometric Progression is seen as

> a geometric progression, also known as a geometric sequence, is a
>   sequence of numbers where each term after the first is found by
>   multiplying the previous one by a fixed, non-zero number called the
>   common ratio. For example, the sequence 2, 6, 18, 54, ... is a
>   geometric progression with common ratio 3. Similarly 10, 5, 2.5, 1.25,
>   ... is a geometric sequence with common ratio 1/2.

(1) It is clearly mentioned that common ratio cannot be zero. That means,
$8,0,0,0,\cdots$ is not a valid Geometric progression because common ratio is zero. Is my understanding right?

(2) But this does not rule out the possibility of having first term zero. If first term is zero, whatever be the common ratio, all other terms will be zero. 
eg: $0,0,0,0,\cdots$. So this must be a valid geometric progression. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Terms of a geometric series are a, ar, a{r^2}, ... where r $is\ not$ 0.

Comment: @Benedict, it is fine. But cannot first term be zero which does not violate the definition?

Comment: How interested can you get in the number 0? I think most folk would assume also that a $is\ not$ 0, either.

Comment: I agree with this (issues $1$ and $2$), though I wonder if there's a particular reason to forbid a zero common ratio.

Comment: Because if you divide the second by the first term to get the common ratio you get undefined. Also third divided by second is another undefined. They may not be a $common$ ratio - being undefined differently!

Comment: Excluding $a=0$ or $r=0$ seems to be a somewhat arbitrary choice. The formula $$a + ar + ar^2 + \cdots + ar^n = a\frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1 - r}$$ remains valid if $a =0$ and/or $r=0$, and what's the point of a geometric sequence if you are not going to sum it? :-)

Comment: @Benedict, yes I agree. But the definition does not prevent a being zero. That is why I got confused whether such a series is allowed.

Comment: Opportunity to re-write the text book - go for it, @Kiran!

Comment: @Bungo, a=0 or r=0 can give problems as  Benedict mentioned. common ratio becomes undefined if we divide second term with first term.

Comment: @Benedict: if the rationale is that one must be able to take the ratio of terms, then the requirement $a\ne0$ goes hand in hand with $r\ne0$.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll mull this over sometime. Maybe next year!

Comment: You gotta have fun in Maths, Eh?

Comment: @Benedict, yes :). But, I was under the impression that maths is one subject where every thing will be well defined. Therefore I never expected this kind of a definition as a student

Comment: Nor did I - thanks for bringing it to my attention. Good luck with the text book though! See you later.

Comment: IMO, if $8,0,0,0\cdots$ is considered invalid because you can't take pairwise ratios, $0,0,0,0\cdots$ is worse. Because in the first case you can anyway infer $a=8,r=0$, while in the second $r$ is completely undefined.

Comment: For my 2 cents.  I would say that the first term equal to 0 would be vaild, even if trivial.

Comment: Can we conclude this as "there is no well defined rule on whether the series is geometric progression or not when first term is zero"?

Comment: The answer purely depends on how we're defining a geometric progression. Based on the way Mathworld [defines it](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSequence.html), there's no restriction of the first term or the common ratio being non-zero. In fact, by that definition, both the examples $\{8,0,0,\ldots\}$ and $\{0,0,\ldots\}$ are valid geometric sequences.

Comment: @learner, one can argue that both these are series with common ratio zero and then it becomes in valid as per the definition that r cannot be zero. it is too confusing statement.

Comment: The point I'm trying to highlight is that the definition which restricts $r$ to be non-zero is not the universal definition as seen from the definition given in MathWorld which doesn't require $r$ to be non-zero.

Comment: ok, got the point. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling what Bungo said, it doesn't actually matter.  If you start with $0$, or the common ratio is $0$, or any other trivial point, the math works out just fine, so to me, it is a matter of not caring because it has no actually impact on anything.